# Rails Contact Form - Email Sent, but not receiving in my inbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails. I have created an app and a simple contact form. When I fill the contact form out it seems to submit everything fine. I don't get any errors, and the console shows that it worked.

However I am not receiving these emails in my inbox or spam folder. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

I followed this [tutorial](https://rubyonrailshelp.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/rails-4-simple-form-and-mail-form-to-make-contact-form/)

**Routes**

```
 match '/contacts',     to: 'contacts#new',             via: 'get'
  resources "contacts", only: [:new, :create]
```

**Contacts Controller**

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
    @contact.request = request
    if @contact.deliver
      redirect_to root_path
      flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you for your message. We will contact you soon!'
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Cannot send message.'
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

**Model**

```
class Contact < MailForm::Base
  attribute :name,      :validate => true
  attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  attribute :message
  attribute :nickname,  :captcha  => true

  # Declare the e-mail headers. It accepts anything the mail method
  # in ActionMailer accepts.
  def headers
    {
      :subject => "My Contact Form",
      :to => "myemail@gmail.com", 
      :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
    }
  end
end
```

**New.html.erb**

```
<div align="center">
  <h3>Send A message to Us</h3>
  <%= simple_form_for @contact, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name, :required => true %>
    <%= f.input :email, :required => true %>
    <%= f.input :message, :as => :text, :required => true %>
    <div class= "hidden">
      <%= f.input :nickname, :hint => 'Leave this field blank!' %>
    </div>
    <div>
      </br>
      <%= f.button :submit, 'Send message', :class=> "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**Create.html.erb**

```
<div>
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div>
      <a href="#" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
        <%= value %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings`, or other delivery method config? You might have to change port in case your provider blocks the one you are using. If they do, you wouldn't get any error but the email wouldn't be delivered.

Comment: ....I don't have that. I'm guessing that is the problem right there.

Comment: Yes definitely. You need to configure some way to actually send the message. Have a look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#example-action-mailer-configuration) for some examples.

Comment: https://gorails.com/episodes/sending-emails-with-mandrill?autoplay=1 you might want to follow this one